# Reading btmon log file

Tags: logs, bluetooth

I'm using `btmon` for monitoring bluetooth packets sent/received from peers. When I run the command `btmon` on my Ubuntu machine, I collect logs as mention below.
I have also read man pages from: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bluez/btmon.1.en.html

I have to figure out which packet to consider as send a packet and which packet to consider as a receive all data.

I observe that there is a Tx and Rx mentioned in log and also a time but I cannot figure out where the packet sending start from and where the packet receiving ends.

Basically, I want to figure out how much time the peer device takes after sending the packet.

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.084811
          ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 130
            Handle: 0x0013
              Data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.085678
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 19                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.085759
          ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 14
            Handle: 0x0013
              Data: 0000000000000000edfa5318
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.086641
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.087638
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.088637
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.132702
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.133698
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.134653
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.135646
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                               [hci0] 20.182235
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 4
            Handle: 0x0010
              Data: 0206
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 17                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.282358
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 12
            Handle: 0x0010
              Data: 000c000007177df11e96
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.301577
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.301615
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.301618
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.301620
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.301622
          ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 130
            Handle: 0x0013
              Data: 0202010c00000718000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.319607
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.319734
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.332684
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.332724
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.333649
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.333696
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.334697
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.334817
          ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 130
            Handle: 0x0013
              Data: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080c0e0f0f0fcfcfeffffffffffffffffffffffffff7f1f1f07070101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.335683
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 19                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.335759
          ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 14
            Handle: 0x0013
              Data: 000000000000000093c682c9
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.336693
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.337651
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.338651
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.382660
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.383658
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.384657
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                     [hci0] 20.385682
            Num handles: 1
            Handle: 3585
            Count: 1
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                               [hci0] 20.432153
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 4
            Handle: 0x0010
              Data: 0206
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 17                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.532366
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 12
            Handle: 0x0010
              Data: 000c0000071845bea32b
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.555377
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.555479
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.555499
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27                                                                                                              [hci0] 20.555514
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x01 dlen 27
```

Can someone explain the btmon log format to me so I can get what I need? Where is the format documented?

Answer (score 0):

`man btmon` tell us it's btsnoop format.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/btsnoop.txt